# Good Tutorials for iPhone programming with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

Are there any good tutorials for iPhone programming using Xcode 4 that cover more than the obvious "Hello World" example. Everything I found so far is either Xcode 3 or Hello World.

Comment: I found no difficulty in transitioning from xcode 3 to xcode 4. Currently all i can think of is the apple's guide for whats new in xcode 4.

Comment: Well as Praveen stated you can use the same tutorial for Xcode 3 in Xcode 4. The major change is that the Interface Builder is no longer a separate program. The rest is more or less the same. Can you give an example of a some Xcode 3 thing you can't find in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCode is just the IDE. It may be a bit tricky if there are certain screenshots, but all in all the file structure is basically the same (Resources folder is now called Supporting Files), and the code is exactly the same - its still objective C, so all the tutorials that use XCode 3 should still be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Go to lynda.com

And download  (iPhone SDK Essential Training )

http://www.lynda.com/iPhone-3-tutorials/iphone-sdk-essential-training/48369-2.html

Answer (score 1):

XCode is ide. if you like means you will develop a ide and you will use to code. ide doesnt matter's so be good in objective c then easy all

Answer (score 0):

Check out Backslash Training's online live offering or local workshops.

http://www.backslashtraining.com

Answer (score 0):

What ur looking for is

Head First iPhone Development
By Dan Pilone, Tracey Pilone
Publisher: O'Reilly Media
Released: October 2009

its the most awesome book out yet. I've tried all the others and this one definitely takes the metaphorical cake, and eats it too :D